# Segmentation fault on strncat

Tags: c, string, char

I have the following code:

```
struct prefix rnp;
char prefix[IPV6_PREFIX_STR_MAX_LEN];

...

strncat(prefix, "/", 1);  <----- WORKS OK
strncat(prefix, rnp.prefixlen, MAX_PREFIX_LEN); <------ SEG FAULT

...
```

Where `rnp.prefixlen`  is of type `u_int8_t`.

```
IPV6_PREFIX_STR_MAX_LEN = 45

MAX_PREFIX_LEN = 2
```

Content of `prefix` is 192.13.6.0 and of `rnp.prefixlen` is 16

I really have no idea about how to overcome it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `prefix` 0-terminated ?

Comment: Are you sure you're setting `rnp.prefixlen` to something?

Comment: @elcanibal , yes it is being used in other locations...

Comment: @cnicutar , are you thinking about memset?

Comment: @Itzik984 That would be an option. So would `prefix[0] = 0;`.

Comment: @WhozCraig , Yes, I have tried it. the macros are IPV6_PREFIX_STR_MAX_LEN = 45 (more than enough in that case,
MAX_PREFIX_LEN = 2, again, should be ok. the content will be added at edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `rnp.prefixlen` is an *integer* (as indicated by the type `u_int8_t`), then you cannot `strncat` it (the integer will be cast to a pointer and then dereferenced, which will cause undefined behaviour).

If your goal is to write some formatted text to a string, use `sprintf` or `snprintf` instead:

```
sprintf(prefix, "/%d", rnp.prefixlen);
```

`sprintf` and `snprintf` return the number of characters written, so you can keep track of the end of the string easily without succumbing to [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).

Comment: Indeed. I question the rationale behind using a non-standard strncat when a standard snprintf provides similar, if not better functionality. +1 on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
strncat(prefix, rnp.prefixlen, MAX_PREFIX_LEN);
```

should be

```
strncat(prefix, rnp.prefixlen, IPV6_PREFIX_STR_MAX_LEN-1);
```

Since IPV6_PREFIX_STR_MAX_LEN is the size of "prefix", and not MAX_PREFIX_LEN. The -1 is because you already consumed 1 byte in the previous line.

Also if **rnp.prefixlen** is of type **u_int8_t**, that means it's NOT a string and it should not be manipulated with strncat. Try to use memcpy/memmove instead.